# List folders in Docker Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, glassfish, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying an application to a pre-configured GlassFish Docker instance running in Elastic Beanstalk. I need to download a library file into a specific folder in the GlassFish directory. So in my `Dockerfile` I put:

```
RUN curl -L -o /mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.34/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar
```

The problem is this doesn't place the file into the specific directory I need. I know the directory relative to the GlassFish source folder, but I need to know where GlassFish is located in the Docker container. I connected to my container by an `ssh` client (putty). And I tried to run a shell in the Docker container in hopes I could interact with it through ssh to find the folder structure:

```
docker run -it amazon/aws-eb-glassfish:4.1-jdk8-onbuild-3.5.1 bash
```

But no such luck. The command seems to do nothing. **How can I view the folder structure of my Docker container that's running in Elastic Beanstalk?**

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question "I need to know where GlassFish is located in the Docker container":

Dockerhub repository for glassfish:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/amazon/aws-eb-glassfish/

Dockerfile is available on github:
https://github.com/aws/aws-eb-glassfish-dockerfiles/blob/master/4.1-jdk8/Dockerfile

From Dockerfile

```
ENV GLASSFISH_HOME /usr/local/glassfish4
```

Hope that helps